# Quartz job not starting

Tags: c#, module, autostart, quartz, abp

I'm trying to use Abp.Quartz for scheduling jobs.

Working with net core 2.2, abp 4.5

I did everything like in docs here
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Quartz-Integration , only resolved it in PostInitialize method.

At the end I tried exactly the same as in docs (start scheduler from controller).

But it not worked too. Job is not starting.

```
namespace Cloud
{
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroCoreModule),
               typeof(AbpQuartzModule))]
    public class CloudCoreModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreInitialize()
        {
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {            
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(CloudCoreModule)
                      .GetAssembly());
        }

        public override void PostInitialize()
        {
             IocManager.Resolve<IQuartzScheduleJobManager>().ScheduleAsync<ApiRequestQueues.ApiRequestProcessor>(
                job =>
                {
                    job
                      .WithIdentity("RevolutApiProcessor")
                      .WithDescription("A job witch processing request front");
                },
                trigger =>
                {
                    trigger
                        .StartNow()
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(
                            schedule =>
                            {
                                schedule
                                    .RepeatForever()
                                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                                    .Build();
                            });

                });
        }
    }
}
```

and here is class ApiRequestProcessor

```
public class ApiRequestProcessor : JobBase, ITransientDependency
{
    public override async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
     //some work
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! I know it's a little bit too late to ask about the problem, but it might help to someone else like me because I've encountered a similar problem. There are 2 entrypoints for investigation:
1. Have you checked logs in your App_Data folder?
2. Have you added [DependsOn(typeof(CloudCoreModule)] to your WebCoreModule?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @plastiquewind - is cloudcoremodule required for Abp.Quartz jobs to work? It's not mentioned in the docs...

Comment: Hi @fullStackChris . It's not mentioned in the docs because CloudCoreModule is not a part of the framework. It's just a custom class mentioned in the original question, you can see it above.

Answer (score 1):

Better late to the party than never.

I've managed to get this working, though without `Abp.Quartz` package. If you're able to use the standard `Quartz` package, you can use the following steps:

1. Define and set up your jobs as normal in `Startup.cs`
2. Ensure that your class implements both `IJob` for `Quartz` to be happy, and `ITransientDependency` for ASP.NET Boilerplate to be happy
3. **Very important**, if your job code uses `DbContext` in any way, you need to ensure that the `[UnitOfWork]` decorator is on your job class (which is anyway important to ensure your jobs run atomically and do not affect any other transactions which may be occurring on your server)

In short, a working bare-bones job class might look like this:

```cs
using System;
using Quartz;

namespace MyProject.MyJobService
{
    [UnitOfWork]
    public class SimpleJob : IJob, ITransientDependency
    {
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from quartz job!");
        }
    }
}
```

More information and discussion can be found here (also how I finally arrived at this solution): https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3757

When in doubt, carefully read what Quartz is telling you in the application output - it usually gives clues as to what is wrong, but I'm confident my solution will work for you